# Format & localize date labels in charts_flutter time series chart

Tags: charts, dart, flutter

I have following time series in [charts_flutter](https://github.com/google/charts/tree/master/charts_flutter):

```
charts.Series<DatumPoint, DateTime>(
        id: 'Series',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (DatumPoint point, _) => point.date,
        measureFn: (DatumPoint point, _) => point.value,
        data: p,
      )
```

and this is how my `TimeSeriesChart` has been created:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      widget.seriesList,
      animate: widget.animate,
      selectionModels: [
        charts.SelectionModelConfig(
          type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
          changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
        )
      ],
      domainAxis: charts.EndPointsTimeAxisSpec(),
      behaviors: [
        charts.LinePointHighlighter(
            showHorizontalFollowLine:
                charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.none,
            showVerticalFollowLine:
                charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.nearest,
            dashPattern: [1, 1]),
        charts.SelectNearest(
          eventTrigger: charts.SelectionTrigger.tapAndDrag,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to format start & end ticker on domain Axis using localize `DateTime` format e.g. `DateFormat.yMMMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode).format(date)`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution from Shruti Gupta is not complete. You have to use a custom `dateTimeFactory` to really localized date.

So create your own `DateTimeFactory`

```
import 'package:charts_common/common.dart' as common show DateTimeFactory;

/// A class to localize the date
class LocalizedTimeFactory implements common.DateTimeFactory {
  final Locale locale;

  const LocalizedTimeFactory(this.locale);

  DateTime createDateTimeFromMilliSecondsSinceEpoch(
      int millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
    return DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  }

  DateTime createDateTime(int year,
      [int month = 1,
        int day = 1,
        int hour = 0,
        int minute = 0,
        int second = 0,
        int millisecond = 0,
        int microsecond = 0]) {
    return DateTime(
        year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond, microsecond);
  }

  /// Returns a [DateFormat].
  DateFormat createDateFormat(String pattern) {
    return DateFormat(pattern, locale.languageCode);
  }
}
```

Then you need to add a `tickFormatterSpec` so your custom dateTimeFactory is taken into account and fill `dateTimeFactory` field:

```
charts.TimeSeriesChart(data.seriesPressure(context),
     defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, strokeWidthPx: 1),
     animate: false,
     domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
        tickFormatterSpec: charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
            hour: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(format: "Hm", transitionFormat: "Hm"),
        ),
     ),
     dateTimeFactory: LocalizedTimeFactory(Localizations.localeOf(context)),
     primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
         tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false))
     ),
```

Your remaining task is to better configure `tickFormatterSpec`. Play with day, hour and minute fields, also with format and transition format until you reach what you want.
I was not able unfortunately to duplicate the display when there is not tickFormatterSpec...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
                      month: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
                        format: 'MMM',
                        transitionFormat: 'MMM yy',
                      ),
                      year: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
                        format: 'YYYY',
                        transitionFormat: 'MMM yy',
                      )),
```